# iOS - Adding a pre-polulated database to Core Data

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I know that this question has been asked a lot of times and I think I've read them all but I still can't solve my bug. This is my code:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let storePath = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.path?.stringByAppendingPathComponent("name.sqlite")
    let fileManager : NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    var fileCopyError:NSError? = NSError()
    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(storePath!) {
        let defaultStorePath : NSString! = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("name", ofType: "sqlite")
        if((defaultStorePath) != nil) {
            println("copying")
            fileManager.copyItemAtPath(defaultStorePath, toPath: storePath!, error: &fileCopyError)
        }
    }
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator?
    coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: storePath!)
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()
```

The problem is that it copies a .sqlite file with the name I used but is empty.

EDIT: FYI I have already cleaned build folder and reseted iPhone Simulator.

Comment: A Core Data store is more than one file (how many files, and how important each is, depends on the options used to create the store). You must move all of the store's files for this to work. This is why moving the files is not the preferred solution, using the migration functionality is.

Comment: How do I use the migration functionality? 

If I move all the files do I need to do this:

    fileManager.copyItemAtPath(defaultStorePath, toPath: storePath!, error: &fileCopyError)

to every file?

Comment: Do not copy the files, you will just run into more problems later. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337261/core-data-design-how-to-have-both-app-data-and-user-data/25523165#25523165